# UIScrollView embedded in other UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uikit

I have a scrollview that contains a UIImageView, with an additional UIScrollView and UIImageView.

[image]

What i’m trying to achieve is to pinch zoom and pan each scrollview independently. If the zoom or panning occur in UIScrollView#1, I would like the scrollView#2 to remain stationary (location relative  to the window). Likewise when zooming or panning in scrollview#2, scrollview#1 will not move.

I tried adding UIScrollView#2 as a subview to UIScrollView#1, however this causes UIScrollView#2 to move

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think adding both scrollviews to a parent view will give you what you want. don't add scrollview#1 as a subview to scrollview#2.